# PHP Warning - Internal Error

Tags: php, wordpress, internal-server-error

I'm working on a website for WordPress and whenever the theme I bought is activated I keep getting an Internal Server Error when i want to add or edit post. Upon activatinh my error log. I get this notification.

---

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'gallery_src' in G:\PleskVhosts\latinaandthecity.tv\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\breeze\inc\meta-box.php on line 150

PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'gallery_id' in *file* on line 151

PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'gallery_src' in *file* on line 152
```

---

When looking at the file, this is what the script is for those lines.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="bluth_custom_thumbnail[gallery_src]" class="source" value="<?php echo $custom_thumbnail['gallery_src']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bluth_custom_thumbnail[gallery_id]" class="image_id" value="<?php echo $custom_thumbnail['gallery_id']; ?>" />
    <a class="blu_add_image" href="#" style="height:auto; min-height: 100px;"> <img class="blu_gallery" data-placeholder="<?php echo $fallback_image; ?>" src="<?php echo $custom_thumbnail['gallery_src']; ?>"> </a>
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here. Please advise?

Comment: What does print_r($custom_thumbnail) give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$custom_thumbnail` variable is set to string and not a associative array. Strings allow only numeric offsets.

Comment: Thank you so much! Once I deleted those lines it worked!